# Size of torsion subgroup of an abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, torsion-groups

Fisrt, let $k$ be a **number field**, and let $A/k$ be an abelian variety. I know that by the Mordell–Weil theorem, $A(k)$ is finitely generated, but I saw [here](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/blms.12952) (in the introduction) that $A(k)_{tors}$ is finite, but I don't understand why. I tries to search for a proof and I saw that is also true in some other settings:

For example, if $A\to C$ is a family of abelian varieties ($C$ is a projective curve), $A/K$ is an abelian variety for a globalfield $K$, so by [Silverman](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0342?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B212%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.439%2C%22y%22%3A0.64%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.785%7D) (theorem C.) if the $K(C)/K$-trace of $A$ is zero, then $A(C)_{tors}$ is finite:

[image]

I don't understant why both of the claims above are true, I will appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: For your first question, subgroups of finitely-generated abelian groups are finitely-generated, and finitely-generated torsion abelian groups are finite.

Comment: @hunter Really nice argument! Thanks

Comment: For your second question, if the trace is zero, then A(C) is finitely generated. So, just like in hunter's argument, it follows that the subgroup A(C)_tor is finite (since finitely generated torsion abelian groups are finite). If you are wondering why the C-points on A are finitely generated, have a look at the Lang-Neron theorem; see http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/Kktrace.pdf This says, in bad notation, that (A/Trace)(C) is finitely generated.